# Can MyBatis log the complete SQL that can run directly

Tags: mysql, sql, logging, mybatis

Can MyBatis log the complete SQL that can run directly

Answer (score 1):

In general case the answer is NO.

If the query has parameters mybatis can't to that even in principle. In order to log the query all parameters should be serialized and represented as strings. For simple data types like `String` or `Integer` this is not a problem but for more complex like `Timestamp` or `Blob` representation may depend on the database.

When query is executed there's no need to convert parameters to strings because JDBC driver passes them to the database in more efficient (and database dependent) format. But for logging purposes mybatis has only java objects and mybatis does not know how to represent them as database specific string literals.

So the best you can have (and this [is supported](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html) in mybatis) is to log the query with placeholders and log parameters used separately. Configure `DEBUG` log level for the logger named after the mapper.

For log4j configuration looks like this:

```
log4j.logger.my.org.myapp.SomeMapper=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the development environment and use IntelliJ, I think plugin `Mybatis Log Plugin` can help you.

And if it is in a production environment, you can copy the log and paste it locally. Then use the plugin feature `Restore Sql from Selection` or `Restore Sql from text`(new version coming soon)

Detailed introduction:
https://github.com/kookob/mybatis-log-plugin

Answer (score 0):

you can copy `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement` to your project directory(keep the same package path) and call `log.info(asSql())` method into after `PreparedStatement.execute.fillSendPacket`. (while using batch operations you can use executeBatchInternal).

Class will be loaded from your project and the origin class will be ignored, you can try this on other framewokrk and database.